# how to create column from delayed function in Dask

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe, dask-delayed

is it possible to create a column from delayed function in Dask?

e.g. if we create a column in pyspark by `df.withColumn('datetime', F.lit(datetime.now())` the value of this column is not calculated until we request.

My question is - can we do similar thing in Dask? As far as i know dask is also lazy by default, but it seems like there is no way to achieve the same result as using pyspark?

Comment: Rather than asking us to translate spark, can you just describe more specifically what you’re trying to do in dask? Also, have you seen the function `dask.dataframe.from_delayed`?

Comment: i have a dataframe and want to add a column that stores the timestamp of the compute time. if i just set the column to `datetime.now()`, the value can differ significantly from the desired one when the computation time is lengthy

a workaround is to set the column after compute, just thinking is there another way to do the work

Comment: Huh. You want an entire column to have the same timestamp over and over? Seems like a good use case for a standalone variable… but yeah you could use `from_delayed` to do this. Alternatively if you want to have the time vary by partition you could map a function which assigns the column using `df.map_partitions`

Comment: If you want implementation help please edit the question to remove the spark references and clarify your goals and then set up a sample problem using code as a [mre]. Thanks!